# NodeJS or MongoDB 1000 limit

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean

I have a NodeJS application that connects to MongoDB. I use AngularJS on my front-end. The NodeJS app contains all my GET, POST, DELETE API. I have a GET request that returns my "Colleges" collection in full as a JSON response. This collection has 7771 documents and I only return the ID and Name as a JSON response.

When I run my application locally on my development environment, it works great and my GET's response is 7771 elements as JSON. When I uploaded my app and went live, I am seeing my GET's response is exactly 1000.

I'm hosting this on a digitalocean droplet. Does DigitalOcean put a limit on API responses? Or is it a configuration in my NodeJS or Mongod due to different versions?

I'm thinking this is to do with versioning of NodeJS and MongoDB in my droplet than my local but before I uninstall and clean install NodeJS and MongoDB in production (still in beta though) that would mean app downtime, I wanted some advice.

Production MongoDB version:

```
app@dev:/etc$ mongod --version
db version v2.4.9
Thu Oct  8 15:03:50.491 git version: nogitversion
app@dev:/etc$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
```

Production NodeJS version:

```
app@dev:/etc$ nodejs --version
v0.10.25
```

Local MongoDB Version:

```
C:\>mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6

C:\>mongod --version
db version v3.0.6
git version: 1ef45a23a4c5e3480ac919b28afcba3c615488f2
```

Local NodeJS Version:

```
C:\>node --version
v4.0.0
```

This is my API code from NodeJS service:

```
exports.listCollegesTypeahead = function(req, res) {
    db.collection('colleges', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({}, {
            name: 1
        }).sort({
            name: 1
        }).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    }); };
```

This code returns all documents (7771) in my local box. In production, only 1000 documents are returned.

P.S: I am listening for NodeJS on port 3000 with a redirect on port 80. My GET requests are via AJAX to "/colleges" that may be going to port 80, not sure that makes a difference.

Re-routing done by:
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000

Comment: It turned out to be a deployment issue with my droplet. The droplet was running nodejs and mongodb that was coming from the ubtuntu repository hosted in digital ocean. The restriction was possibly coming from running older versions.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a deployment issue with my production droplet. The droplet was running nodejs and mongodb that was coming from the ubtuntu repository hosted in digital ocean. The restriction was possibly coming from running older versions.

After updating to NodeJS v4.0.0 and MongoDB v3.0.6 on my production server, I was able to see my GET request now returning 7771 records as expected.

After doing a apt-get remove and purge of "mongodb" and "nodejs", I ran the following to install NodeJS v4.1.2:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After this, I followed this guide to install mongodb 3.0.6
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/